# How to implement expandable content in a bootstrap panel

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, panel

I want a bootstrap panel with a specific height where the textoverflow in the panel body is hidden.

When the user clicks on a visual element implemented as a pull down tab at the bottom, the content expands.

Is there something built in to bootstrap that I am missing or is this best done by rolling my own?

```
<div class="panel panel-danger ">
    <div class="panel-heading">
         <h3 class="panel-title">Welcome Bulletin</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" style="height:100px; overflow:hidden">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Shred/Lm7md5bh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class and use [**jquery toggleclass**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) whenever the trigger button is clicked.

```
.panel-preview {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here's the [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm7md5bh/10/).

Also, Bootstrap has a built-in [**jquery plugin**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) to toggle elements. However, this toggles the display property of the element, not the height.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
      Collapsible Group Item #1
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
  <div class="panel-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
      Collapsible Group Item #2
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
  <div class="panel-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
      Collapsible Group Item #3
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
  <div class="panel-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
  </div>
</div>
```